# Trouble implementing multi-leg journey search using PL/pgSQL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization, plpgsql

Context:
I'm currently working on a project where I need to implement a search functionality for multi-leg journeys using PL/pgSQL in PostgreSQL. I've designed tables for voyage, trajet, and reservation in my database.

Problem Description:
I'm encountering difficulties in creating a PL/pgSQL function that should search for journeys with multiple correspondences based on user-provided information like departure city, arrival city. The goal is to retrieve possible journeys with compatible timings (departure and arrival times). I've tried various approaches with PL/pgSQL, but I'm struggling to structure the recursive search for multiple legs without hitting errors related to time calculations and recursive function calls.

```
drop table jabaianb.reservation;
drop table jabaianb.voyage ;
drop table jabaianb.trajet ;
drop table jabaianb.utilisateur ;

CREATE TABLE jabaianb.utilisateur (
 id SERIAL ,
 identifiant VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 pass VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 nom VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 prenom VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 avatar VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (id) );


CREATE TABLE jabaianb.trajet (
 id SERIAL ,
 depart VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
 arrivee VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
 distance INT NULL , 
 PRIMARY KEY (id) );


CREATE TABLE jabaianb.voyage (
 id SERIAL ,
 conducteur INT NULL ,
 trajet INT NULL ,
 tarif INT NULL , 
 nbPlace INT NULL ,
 heureDepart INT NULL ,
 contraintes VARCHAR(500),   
 PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
 CONSTRAINT jabaianb.utilisateur
 FOREIGN KEY (conducteur)
 REFERENCES jabaianb.utilisateur (id )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT jabaianb.trajet
 FOREIGN KEY (jabaianb.trajet)
 REFERENCES jabaianb.trajet (id )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE jabaianb.reservation (
 id SERIAL ,
 voyage INT NULL ,
 voyageur INT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
 CONSTRAINT jabaianb.utilisateur
 FOREIGN KEY (voyageur)
 REFERENCES jabaianb.utilisateur (id )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT jabaianb.voyage
 FOREIGN KEY (jabaianb.voyage)
 REFERENCES jabaianb.voyage (id )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

What I've Tried:
I've attempted to create a PL/pgSQL function that iterates through the database, checking for compatible journeys and correspondences. I've used recursive calls within the function to handle multiple legs of the journey. However, I'm facing issues with time calculations, as well as errors related to function parameters and table returns.

Expected Outcome:
I expect the PL/pgSQL function to return a set of viable journeys with their corresponding legs and timings, meeting the user-provided criteria of departure city, arrival city, and the number of travelers.

Any insights, guidance, or alternative approaches on how to structure the PL/pgSQL function for this multi-leg journey search would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rechercher_voyages_correspondances(
    ville_dep VARCHAR,
    ville_arr VARCHAR
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    id_voyage INT,
    heure_depart INT,
    ville_depart VARCHAR,
    ville_arrivee VARCHAR
) AS $$
DECLARE
    record_voyage RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Recherche des voyages directs
    FOR record_voyage IN
        SELECT v.id AS id_voyage, v.heureDepart AS heure_depart, t.depart AS ville_depart, t.arrivee AS ville_arrivee
        FROM jabaianb.voyage as  v
        JOIN jabaianb.trajet as t ON v.trajet = t.id
        WHERE t.depart = ville_dep
            AND t.arrivee = ville_arr
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;

    -- Recherche des correspondances
    FOR record_voyage IN
        SELECT v1.id AS id_voyage, v1.heureDepart AS heure_depart, t1.depart AS ville_depart, t2.arrivee AS ville_arrivee
        FROM jabaianb.voyage v1
        JOIN jabaianb.trajet t1 ON v1.trajet = t1.id
        JOIN jabaianb.voyage v2 ON v1.trajet = v2.trajet
        JOIN jabaianb.trajet t2 ON v2.trajet = t2.id
        WHERE t1.depart = ville_dep
            AND t2.arrivee = ville_arr
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: This looks like the "traveling salesman" problem

Comment: If you're allowed to use PostgreSQL extensions, you don't have to build things from scratch: consider [pgrouting](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstraCost.html) or [Apache-AGE](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/match.html#directed-edges-and-variable). You might want to fill in some details in your question: you mentioned errors but you didn't show any, there's no sample data to try this out on and reproduce the error(s), there's no example output based on sample input, no desired "correct" output example.